# Why does gdb prompt "Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/xxxxx' in core file."?

Tags: linux, gdb, debian

My OS is `Debian`, when using `gdb` to analyze one core dump file, the following info is got:

```
......
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/67327' in core file.
.....
```

Could anyone explain why the warning ("`Unexpected size of section '.reg-xstate/67327' in core file.`") is prompted?

P.S., my `gdb` version is:

```
$ gdb
GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6+b1) 7.12.0.20161007-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this post is rather old but I just hit this and this post is the top google result.

While it is possible the core dump is truncated, this is rather unlikely because the `.reg-xstate` section of the core dump is stored near the very begining of the file. A much more likely cause of the issue is that the version of GDB in use does not understand a newer processor feature that has been added to the XSAVE area (aka the xstate).

Since I'm using the same version of GDB (7.12) as the OP is, I'm gonna guess that they were also running on a Skylake or newer CPU. Skylake CPUs can support something called Memory Protection Keys and as part of this a new register named PKRU was added to the XSAVE area. Support for this new register was added in GDB 8.

Comment: I'm seeing the same on gdb 9, but suspect the explanation is similar: the kernel is adding entries to the core that gdb doesn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

> `Unexpected size of section`.reg-xstate/67327' in core file.`

It is likely that your `core` file is truncated. This could happen if your `ulimit -c` is set too low, or if you ran out of disk space while the `core` was being written.

The pseudo-section `.reg-xstate/67327` is supposed to contain AVX extended-register state for thread 67327, saved via `XSAVE` instruction. Here is a [patch](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2010-02/msg00010.html) that added this support to BFD (and the kernel later in the message).

Comment: But my core file size is "`unlimited`" and the disk space is also enough. It is weird.