# GDB core dump analysis inside a docker container

Tags: c++, docker, gdb

I'm trying to do a post mortem analysis using gdb on a C++ application inside a docker container. I have increased `ulimit`, added `SYS_PTRACE` capability, and used `seccomp=unconfined`. But when I use gdb and the main application with debug symbols I see this error:

```
warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/10734' in core file.

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/10734' in core file.
#0  0x00007f05ce755350 in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f04d3ffe700 (LWP 10734))]
(gdb) 
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f05ce755350 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f05cea2382f in ?? ()
#2  0x00007f0000000008 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007f05ced76c40 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f04d3ffdd50 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f05ce897d69 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f05ced76c40 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f04d3ffdd70 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f04d3ffdd90 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f05ce89796c in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f04d3ffdd90 in ?? ()
#11 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Why is this happening when the ulimit is unlimited?

```
root@57a1bc01c676:/workspace/builddir# ulimit 
unlimited
```

Comment: Was the application built with debug symbols?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that this is built with debug symbols in the main question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does gdb prompt "Unexpected size of section \`.reg-xstate/xxxxx' in core file."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047779/why-does-gdb-prompt-unexpected-size-of-section-reg-xstate-xxxxx-in-core-file)

Comment: Nope, I saw that question. My gdb version is 8.1.

Comment: Yes, but I guess the solution was updating to a newer gdb version right? "Support for this new register was added in GDB 8.1"

Comment: I don't have a fancy processor so hopefully, this shouldn't be a problem.
`
lscpu 
Architecture:        x86_64 
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              16
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9800X CPU @ 3.80GHz
`

Comment: you sure the sources are within the docker as well? or only the binary?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the binary and the sources are inside the docker container.

Comment: I just hit the same problem. Was the core dump generated in the docker container? I am able to do a postmortem if the core dump also generated in the docker. If the core dump was generated in virtual in openstack I have to use also virtualized instance in openstack. Using docker didn't work.